# Does eclipse have Graphviz plug-in?

Tags: eclipse, graphviz, plantuml

I install a plantuml plug-in in eclipse, which depends on Graphviz. Does eclipse have Graphviz plug-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,Eclipse has Graphviz plug-in
Follow these link

http://www.graphviz.org/content/how-start

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/category/free-tagging/graphviz